# How do I position a div next to a mouse click using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I position a div next to a mouse click using JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a little more specifics?

Comment: @XstreamINsanity ...OK I have a table & when you click a certain cell it loads something into a DIV. What I want to do is display this DIV where I just clicked. Let me know if this makes sense?

Comment: Do you want to display mouse pointer location where click on DIV or do function when click on DIV?

Comment: So you want to fill the cell with a DIV tag you've already created?  Is this DIV already nested somewhere else on the page or just in the code?

Comment: @Nasir Do you want to create a context menu using a div? I'm trying to solve the same problem myself.

Comment: @Nasir If you want to use a div as a context menu, you can refer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can try:

```
$( "td").click( function(event) {
  $("#divId").css( {position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX});
});
```

After additional question was asked in the comment:

```
$( "td").click( function(event) {
  var div = $("#divId");
  div.css( {
      position:"absolute", 
      top:event.pageY, 
      left: event.pageX});

  var delayTimer = setTimeout( function( ) {
        $that.fadeIn( "slow");
     }, 100);

  div.mouseover( function( event) {
     if (delayTimer)
         clearTimeout( delayTimer);
  }).mouseout( function(){
     if (delayTimer)
         clearTimeout( delayTimer);
     var $that = $(this);
     delayTimer = setTimeout( function( ) {
        $that.fadeOut( "slow");
     }, 500)         
  });
});
```

Comment: Great thanks a trillion it worked...Do you know how I can stop the DIV displaying out of this table I'm clicking in?

Comment: Here's the concept I'm thinking of:

if($('#DayInfo'). is outside of $('#holiday-planner-table')) {

display $('#DayInfo') with minus co-ordinates

}
else{ do your code }

Comment: Consider open new thread with new question describing your additional problem.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle demo for this example? It would be useful to have a working demo of this script.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle for those Who need it ------------->

JSFIDDLE - - - - - -> http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/aFACA/

Comment: doesn't work with long pages with scroll bar. I used `position:fixed` to display content.

Comment: this works great. however what if I have a `.draggable` jquery UI component. and I have defined a snap grid, how would I make this draggable snap to the closest pageX of the snap grid I've defined?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$('#cell').bind('click',
    function(e){
        $('#div').css('left',e.pageX + 'px' );
        $('#div').css('top',e.pageY + 'px' ); });
```

The div's position should be set to absolute.