# How to show a div and move it to the mouse's position on click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have one link which opens a div and it works fine, but I cannot make it to move to location of mouse click. Code is as follows:

Link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_popup('my_popup')" id="napFilt">Filter</a>
```

Function:

```
 function show_popup(id) {               
     if (document.getElementById){ 
         obj = document.getElementById(id); 
         if (obj.style.display == "none") {
             obj.style.display = "";
         } 
     } 
 }
```

Using JS, how can I make the displayed div move to the position of the mouse click?

Comment: A similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521248/how-do-i-position-a-div-next-to-a-mouse-click-using-jquery

Comment: You need a pure javascript solution?

Comment: Yes I would like pure javascript! If it is possible! katspaugh I am looking in bootstrap but would like to know "vanila" solution.

Comment: Folks, he's clearly asking for a plain JS solution. Please stop flagging this as a duplicate of questions surrounding jQuery and other frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the div you are "spawning" is in the body tag. It sould have "position: absolute;" as css property.
Then you do this: http://jsfiddle.net/GSxNx/5/

I leave this pretty uncommented here since i commented source code there. ;)
Only one thing: This is NOT! crossbrowser tested. It works though pretty well in FF 16.0 ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. This works very well. I tried it on Chrome and IE 9 and it works very well. Ivan