# Position <div> tag where clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to position a `<div>` element where I click.

This is the div that I want to position

```
<main class="">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Breadcrumb)
    <div class="split">
        <div class="half">
            <div class="section-head">
                <i class="section-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>
                <h2>mon Calendrier</h2>
                <small>Dates à retenir</small>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar-container">
                <!-- CALENDAR -->
                <div class="action-calendar"></div>
                <!-- TOOLTIP -->
                <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
                    <div class = "day-event">
                        <span class="title"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

This is binded to an event on a calendar (if I have a date which has an event associated with it).
What I want to obtain is , as soon as I click on a date I want this `<div>` to be placed where the mouse was clicked.

Found this in my search for something that could help me 
[[How do I position a div next to a mouse click using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521248/how-do-i-position-a-div-next-to-a-mouse-click-using-jquery][1]) but it didn't helped me. The div was changing position but not even close on where I clicked.

This is the code that should do the trick:

```
var tooltip_HTML = $(".day-event .title").html();
var position = $(".action-calendar a.ui-state-active").parent().offset();
$(".tooltip-wrapper").css({ top: position.top, left: position.left })
```

THE CSS

```
.tooltip-wrapper .title{
    color:#ffffff; 
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.tooltip-wrapper{
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 2000;
    width: 100%
}

.tooltip-wrapper .day-event {
    background: #000000; 
    position: relative; 
    width:250px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    /*height: 100px;*/ 
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;  
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: Alpha(opacity=90);
    z-index: 10000;
}

.tooltip-wrapper span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

The thing is that it changes the position but not where it suppose.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like `event.pageY` and `event.pageX` should be `e.pageY` and `e.pageX`

Answer (score 2):

The`event.pageX` and `event.pageY` gets you the horizontal and vertical position of the mouse with respect to the **uppermost left** part of the **page**. When you're setting `position: absolute`. It's top and left value will get set with respect to it's **relative parent container**.

Thus your getting the wrong coordinates.
To fix this, you have to set the parent container just after the `<body>` and set it's `width: 100%;` Set the parents container `position: relative;`. Now since you've got the whole page width and height, `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`will give you right coordinates for `top`and `left` positions

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a typo. You should update your `event.pageY`, `event.pageX` with `e.pageY`, `e.pageX`.

```
var container = $(".action-calendar");
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
          tooltip_HTML = $(".day-event .title").html();
          $(".day-event .title").html(tooltip_HTML);
          $(".day-event").fadeOut(500);
     }
     var monthEvents = $('td.dayEvent');
     $.each(monthEvents, function (key, td) {
     var x = $(td).children().attr('id', 'dayEvent-' + key);
     });
     $(".tooltip-wrapper").css({ position: "absolute", top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX });
});
```

And by the way, I don't know your `.tooltip-wrapper`'s details. But this element shouldn't have a parent which has relative position. Because if it has, `.tooltip-wrapper` will position itself by its own parent.