# Present custom menu on right click Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly

Is it possible to present a custom sub-menu when a user right clicks a plotly chart, instead of the default one?

[image: Default right click]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an event to `contextmenu` plotly container.

Here is the reference to `contextmenu` docs -
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu

You will have prevent the default behaviour of context menu so that the browsers default context menu doesn't overlap with yours.

You can use this

```
document.querySelector('#plotly-container').addEventListender('contextmenu', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Your code here
});
```

In the callback function, you need to identify the mouse position with `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` and position a container absolutely at those co-ordinates.

You can refer to this question to understand how to create a div container next to your mouse position.

[How do I position a div next to a mouse click using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521248/how-do-i-position-a-div-next-to-a-mouse-click-using-jquery)

You can refer to this question to understand more on how to bind `contextmenu` event.

[How can I capture the right-click event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript)

Comment: I will try this as soon as possible. Thank you!